# How to keep logs of your users in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, logging, laravel, laravel-4

I have `users` table in my database lay out like this :

- id
- username
- firstname
- lastname
- email
- photo

As of now, since I am an `Admin` user so I have `Admin right`, and I can Create, Update, and Delete. 
I want to allow all my users to have the same right as me later on. 
Before I release this feature, I want to keep track on who edit what - so things doesn't get lost, and it's good to keep the history of things.

What is best practice for this feature ?
I know that I have do some programming logic in my update function in my Controller function.
I know that I have to create a `logs` table on my database to store

- user_id : who make a change
- created_at : when the change was made
- old_data: string
- new_data: string

For someone, that had any experiences with this feature, can you PLEASE give me some advice ? 
I really appreciate your concern. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think best approach to this problem is each action that a user takes that you want to log should also fire an event.

```
Event::fire('some.event', array(Auth::user()));
```

Then you can register listeners for each event and log appropriately.

```
Event::listen('some.event', function($user)
{
    // create new item in logs table here.
});
```

Comment: Which function/file should these code go to ? If you don't mind clarify a little bit more..

Comment: This is indeed a good way to do this. You can read up more on the Event listeners in the Laravel docs. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events

Comment: I had my response typed out at work and never sent it.  As Colin Schoen said, the docs are a good place to start.  Basically you'd put the fire method anywhere you wish to log and send it an array of variables which you would like to log.  The listener can go anywhere in your app that is being autoloaded.  `app/start/global.php` is usually a quick and dirty way to do it, the better way being service providers.